# Add Tooltip in fl_chart pie chart flutter

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

i am creating a pie chart using fl_chart. I am finding it difficult to add a tooltip on hovered pies to display the values. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried creating custom tooltips but they keep opening in the wrong location of the screeen

Comment: use LineTouchData

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.